# Java: Antlr4 MySql get individual statements

Tags: java, mysql, antlr, antlr4

I'm using Java with JDBC to run MySql code. I want to execute a DDL script, but JDBC can only execute a single statement at a time, which makes it unsuitable to execute a whole .sql file out of the box.

What I'm trying to do is use Antlr4 to parse the .sql file so I can break up each individual statement and then iteratively execute them with JDBC.

I've gotten this far:

```
InputStream resourceAsStream = Main.class.getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("an-arbitrary-ddl.sql");
CharStream codePointCharStream = CharStreams.fromStream(resourceAsStream);
MySqlLexer tokenSource = new MySqlLexer(new CaseChangingCharStream(codePointCharStream, true));
TokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(tokenSource);
MySqlParser mySqlParser = new MySqlParser(tokenStream);
// Where do I go from here?
```

I'm sure I'm just not searching for the correct terms because I'm new to Antlr and manually parsing code. I can't find any reference from here as to what I need to do to get individual sql statements out of the `MySqlParser`. What do I need to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this can be improved, however, as the most simple way I could create this was creating a listener and provide the constructor with a `Consumer<String>` object. The listener looks at individual statements and recursively constructs them. There is probably a more optimal solution, however, I no longer have time to try to optimize this if there is.

```
/**
 * @author Paul Nelson Baker
 * @see <a href="https://github.com/paul-nelson-baker/">GitHub</a>
 * @see <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/paul-n-baker/">LinkedIn</a>
 * @since 2018-09
 */
public class SqlStatementListener extends MySqlParserBaseListener {

    private final Consumer<String> sqlStatementConsumer;

    public SqlStatementListener(Consumer<String> sqlStatementConsumer) {
        this.sqlStatementConsumer = sqlStatementConsumer;
    }

    @Override
    public void enterSqlStatement(MySqlParser.SqlStatementContext ctx) {
        if (ctx.getChildCount() > 0) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            recreateStatementString(ctx.getChild(0), stringBuilder);
            stringBuilder.setCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1, ';');
            String recreatedSqlStatement = stringBuilder.toString();
            sqlStatementConsumer.accept(recreatedSqlStatement);
        }
        super.enterSqlStatement(ctx);
    }

    private void recreateStatementString(ParseTree currentNode, StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
        if (currentNode instanceof TerminalNode) {
            stringBuilder.append(currentNode.getText());
            stringBuilder.append(' ');
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < currentNode.getChildCount(); i++) {
            recreateStatementString(currentNode.getChild(i), stringBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Next you need to traverse the statements, the string consumer from earlier allows you to lazily redirect the output wherever you need. This can be as simple as just printing to stdout, however, it can just as easily be used to append to a list.

```
public List<String> mySqlStatementsFrom(String sourceCode) {
    List<String> statements = new ArrayList<>();
    mySqlStatementsToConsumer(sourceCode, statements::add);
    return statements;
}

public void mySqlStatementsToConsumer(String sourceCode, Consumer<String> mySqlStatementConsumer) {
    CharStream codePointCharStream = CharStreams.fromString(sourceCode);
    MySqlLexer tokenSource = new MySqlLexer(new CaseChangingCharStream(codePointCharStream, true));
    TokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(tokenSource);
    MySqlParser mySqlParser = new MySqlParser(tokenStream);

    SqlStatementListener statementListener = new SqlStatementListener(mySqlStatementConsumer);
    ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(statementListener, mySqlParser.sqlStatements());
}
```

Comment: Have you profiled your solution? How long does it take for, say, a 1 Mio lines file?

Comment: Do you have a 1 Mio file I can use? I will if you have one available, but like I said I want to get better at Antlr. Once I understand how to properly use Antlr, I can then optimize. Otherwise such optimization is premature. While I can appreciate your solution breaks scripts into individual statements very quickly, I'm more concerned about having a general solution I can expand from (say multiple SQL dialects, or even something not SQL related at all) as opposed to a one off solution that is only applicable to this individual case and doesn't teach me more about language processing/parsing.

Answer (score 0):

A parser is not the right tool for this kind of problem. A statement splitter is pretty easy to write manually and much faster if you do it yourself. I implemented such a splitter in C++ in [MySQL Workbench](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/modules/db.mysql.parser/src/mysql_parser_module.cpp#L2279). Shouldn't be difficult to port this to Java. The code is very fast (1 Mio LOC SQL code in under 1 sec on an average machine). A parser would need **much** longer.

Comment: While I appreciate your answer, it doesn't actually help me in my situation. I have done simple solutions like this before, however, I want to be better at using Antlr which is why I went out of my way to use it. More unfortunately, there are probably people who have to use Antlr for their project requirements and may stumble upon this answer while looking for resources, which won't help them either.